# Checklist field not decoding option labels while other field types do

Tags: content-editor

On my 9.3 instance (with latest cumulative hotfix), I have 3 different field types, all of which have the same source:

- Multilist
- Droplink
- Checklist

One of the selectable items has an HTML entity encoded display name, meaning that the raw value of the `__Display name` field is `GST &#40;Gulf Standard Time - GMT+04:00&#41;`. If you are curious about how I got into this scenario, see [this post about display name field encoding changes](https://mikael.com/2021/02/an-important-breaking-change-in-sitecore-item-displayname/).

As you can see in the rendered fields below, droplink and multilist fields appear to decode this value prior to displaying, whereas the checklist does not.

[image: multilist field]
[image: droplink and checklist field]

I know for a fact that the multilist and droplink fields have some type of JS running a decode on the labels because the raw HTML that is returned from the network call is encoded:

[image: multilist encoded]

This looks like a bug, and it's not clear what is performing this decoding. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Checklist` field does the whole rendering in backend code.

You can find it in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Checklist` class in the `Sitecore.Kernel` assembly.

`RenderOptions` method goes through all the options and creates `DataChecklistItem` object for every option without any encoding.

In order to fix it, you can create a class inheriting from original Sitecore `Checklist` class, override `OnLoad` method like below and fix encoding for every `DataChecklistItem`:

```
namespace MyAssembly.MyNamespace
{
    public class Checklist : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Checklist
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            if (!Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
                FixEncoding();
        }

        private void FixEncoding()
        {
            foreach (var control in Controls)
            {
                var dataChecklistItem = control as Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.DataChecklistItem;

                if (dataChecklistItem != null)
                {
                    dataChecklistItem.Header = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dataChecklistItem.Header);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to register your custom namespace where you added the class in config with your prefix, e.g. `customized`:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
      <controlSources>
        <source assembly="MyAssembly" namespace="MyAssembly.MyNamespace" prefix="customized" mode="on"/>
      </controlSources>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And finally you have to set that prefix on the field type `/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/Checklist` in `core` database:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. I have notified Sitecore and will update this post if anything noteworthy comes up.